# Modify value only if node is new

Tags: 7, nodes

I am using the following function to alter the node's data before saving it to the database.

```
function mymodule_node_presave($node) {
  if ($node->type="mytype") {
    if ($node->is_new) {
      $node->status = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

How do I know that the node is new and not updated/edited? In the example, you may see I have used `$node->is_new`, and I need to make sure that is correct. So is it?

Comment: Surely the easiest way to find that out would be to try it?

Comment: @Clive yeah but i expect that a person like you with many years of experience with drupal would comment with yes or no and i'll take the answer for good. :)

Comment: can you check if the $node object exists yet?

Comment: rules module has 'event after saving content' you can try it.

Comment: @Vlasin Fair enough ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `is_new` property is set by the [node_save](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) function, which is the same function that will invoke [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) - so your are safe in your assumption that this property will be present.

If you were not doing this in hook_node_presave, another way of testing if a node is new is by checking if the `nid` property is present and non-zero:

```
if (empty($node->nid)) {
  // ... this is a new node ...
}
```

Comment: ok , thanks , after some digging as Clive suggested i discovered the answer myself.